# Overwriting Materialize 1.0.0 radio style

Tags: css, materialize

I've modified & used Materialize 0.100.2 to look appropriate for print, and am trying to **upgrade to [1.0.0](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.css)**.

The change I am having trouble with is making the `radio`'s filled-in-dot black. Can someone point out what style (selector?) I am missing?

The CSS below seems to work on `screen` only *(if i change the `@media`)*, but doesn't view properly on `print`.

***Controls on screen:***
[image: Screen - Controls]

***Expected from print (tested working on screen):***
[image: Print - Expected]

***Result from print:***
[image: Print - Result]

Last lines of my override CSS I have:

```
@media print {
    /*  Radio Disabled Text  */
    [type="radio"]:disabled + span {
        color: #000000 !important;
    }

    /*  Outer Box - Unchecked  */
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in:not(:checked) + span:not(.lever):after {
        border: 2px solid #000000 !important;
    }

    /*  Outer Box - Checked  */
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):after {
        border: 2px solid #000000 !important;
        background-color: #ffffff !important;
    }

        /*  Inner Mark  */
        [type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):before {
            border-right: 2px solid #000000 !important;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000000 !important;
        }

    /*  Outer Circle - Unchecked  */
    [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span:before, [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span:after {
        border: 2px solid #000000 !important;
    }

    /*  Outer Circle - Checked  */
    [type="radio"]:checked + span:after, [type="radio"].with-gap:checked + span:before, [type="radio"].with-gap:checked + span:after {
        border: 2px solid #000000 !important;
    }

        /*  Inner Circle - Checked  */
        [type="radio"]:checked + span:after, [type="radio"].with-gap:checked + span:after {
            /*  should fill in the dot  */
            background-color: #000000 !important;
        }
}
```

Comment: Check this : https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/PyEYjx , if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: They actually have the exact problem I have. Specifically, check in the **Red** option & attempt to print. I might just have to use the **Yellow**'s style, if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I opened the issue - https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6175 3 days ago but no reply.